# couchdb 1.0.1 etc/init.d/couchdb start prompts password

Tags: passwords, installation, couchdb

I have created a user "couchdb" and installed couchdb 1.0.1 from source, I have also given permission for the user "couchdb" as given in http://chrismckee.co.uk/setting-up-couchdb-on-ubuntu/. Also rather than  installing couchdb  in the default location i used prefix option to change the location. Now when i start the couchdb  form the installed path it prompts for a password. I have not set the password during installation. Can some one please let know is couchdb has created a default password or how to disable password option.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use "/yourlocation/bin/couchdb" to start the CouchDB instance instead of "/yourlocation/etc/init.d/couchdb start"

Answer (score 2):

With 1.0.1 just using "couchdb -b" worked for me. (-b = spawn as a background process)